# how to upload social media to html code?

Tags: html

I downloaded designmodo Flat social media icons. I want to use the facebook icon on my webpage. My code in sublime text 2 is

```
<img src="facebook.png"/>
```

When I open a browser in firefox, the icon doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you provide us with the directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 1):

The icon is not available at the URL you specified in the `src` attribute of your `img` element. Make the icon available at the URL you specify in the `src` attribute of your `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
<img src="facebook.png"/>
```

you are asking the page to fetch the file `facebook.png` in the same url as folder as your `.html` file. All paths in html are **relative paths** to the images, starting at the folder containing the `.html` file.